# Api Platform custom controller with custom JSON body

Tags: symfony, swagger, swagger-ui, api-platform.com

I'm trying to create a custom action/controller/operation in Api-platform.

Basically, i need a custom action documented in Swagger but not as `ApiResource` since the JSON body the action receives does not have a corresponding entity in the database.

The body would look something like this:

```
[
    {
       "someEntityId": "2",
       "message": "test message",
       "userId": "11"
    },
    {
       "someEntityId": "8",
       "message": "test message two",
       "userId": "16"
    }
]
```

As i said i cannot have a `ApiResource` since that would break REST principles and entity with these fields does not exist. I'm using this data to perform some custom business logic and this JSON is deserialized into a `DTO`, to be precise collection of `DTOs`.

Regular Symfony controller with routing should be the way to go, at least i think, but i can't get this route to show up in `Swagger` even with annotations for a controller.

I've tried this:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     methods={"POST"},
 *     name="api_post_notify_users",
 *     path="/api/users/notify_users",
 * )
 * @SWG\Post(
 *      path="/api/users/notify_users",
 *      summary="Summary",
 *      description="Description",
 *      produces={"application/json"},
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response=200,
 *         description="Success",
 *     )
 * )
 * @return Response
 */
public function __invoke()
{
    $data = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->getContent();

    return new Response($data);
}
```

Not sure what am i missing. Also, is there a way to validate this JSON array against the `DTO` so to be sure that all fields in JSON are being sent.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: How did you do it ? Can you post solution here ?

Answer (score 0):

Create the DTO of your response with all your fields, then deserialize it with the symfony serializer. You can then call the Symfony Validator or each of your DTO created and return your response accordingly.